# How to implement Dragable circle in google map api2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to drag a circle on google map api2 with my finger,But unable to move because it moving map also.
If anyone have solution.Please reply.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Create a circular `Marker` image, then allow the user to drag it (using `draggable(true)` on your `MarkerOptions`).